# Mapping to a controller manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to follow along with this [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Managing-incremental-consent-and-conditional-access). I need to manually map to a controller using `app.UseEndpoints`.

the below is the route I need to manually map to. Full controller code here [see code here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs)

```
 [Area("MicrosoftIdentity")]
 [Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]
```

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    // what do I need to change here? <---
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "MicrosoftIdentity",
        pattern: "MicrosoftIdentity/Account/{action}");
});
```

Comment: It has double slash in `[Route("[area]/[controller]//[action]")]`. You did it intentionally?

Comment: No sorry. I've removed it now

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify the fixed controller route before the default.

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    // what do I need to change here? <---
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "MicrosoftIdentity",
        pattern: "MicrosoftIdentity/Account/{action}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


});
```